# Converting SOAP XML to JSON in using .Net based Web services

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, json, soap

I am developing an Mobile Web App. I consume a SOAP XML based web service. But based on this thread [Why is it not a good idea to use SOAP for communicating with the front end (ie web browser)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127038/why-is-it-not-a-good-idea-to-use-soap-for-communicating-with-the-front-end-ie-we), I am planning to use JSON instead of SOAP XML.

Is there any library that will convert a SOAP based XML in to JSON format in .Net?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). It is capable of converting JSON to and from XML.

Comment: XML != SOAP XML (as requested)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a separate library to coax JSON out of ASP.NET services, long as you're okay with using POST requests and no GET requests.  Here's an example of using jQuery to retrieve JSON from an ASMX service, for exmaple: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/