# calling a java webservice from html page and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, web-services

I'm trying to call a java implemented web service (using the NetBeans IDE) from javascript. I have read a lot about jQuery and AJAX but i cant seem to get a hand on it.

suppose my web service WSDL is found at: http://localhost:8080/MICE_Server/MapEditorService?WSDL

web method name : sayHello(String name) which returns a string.

how would i be able to to this in javascript?

thanks in advance for ur help!!

Comment: Show us some code. If we can see your attempt, we can tell you where you are going wrong. That is going to be a lot more helpful than a spoonfed example that you don't understand any more then the other examples you've seen.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JQuery, there is a [SOAP client plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient) that you might be interested in.

Also, you may want to see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript/1695390#1695390) may be especially helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to use jQuery, I think it might be easier to just use [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) here. You can call the webservice method from the DWR backend method which can be invoked from a java script. It's pretty easy to set up. They have a good collection of tutorials on their website as well.