# Javascript client for JIRA RPC API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, xml-rpc, jira

Anyone know of a Javascript (jquery or otherwise is fine too) client library for accessing [JIRAs XML-RPC API](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+XML-RPC+Client)? Even just some examples of an xml-rpc call (to JIRA) from js would be useful.

I know they have a [new SOAP/Json API](http://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/latest/) but I'm working against an older corporate JIRA installation that uses 3.13 and does not support the new API.

Answer (score 2):

JIRA has had XML-RPC and SOAP since v3.manyyearsago. The new REST API in 4.2 is mostly read-only and provides JSON but is still under active development. The best documented choice is the existing SOAP API but if you need to use Javascript to call it, see the following pages:

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+a+SOAP+Client?focusedCommentId=1507396#comment-1507396

[Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)

[calling a java webservice from html page and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675776/calling-a-java-webservice-from-html-page-and-javascript)