# How to post a SOAP request from a browser?

Tags: xml, soap, webclient

Is it possible to send a SOAP request directly from a browser to service provider?  And then parse the output in javascript to show the result?

For example, if I've a SOAP request [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_example.asp) :

```
POST /InStock HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: nnn

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">

<soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock">
  <m:GetStockPrice>
    <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>
  </m:GetStockPrice>
</soap:Body>

</soap:Envelope>
```

Then can I get the 'IBM stock price' by clicking on a link on a web page? And show result after xml processing.

Comment: Probably answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is a JavaScript SOAP library.

I don't have a lot of experience with any of them, but a quick Google search turned up

- http://www.codeproject.com/kb/Ajax/JavaScriptSOAPClient.aspx
- http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/
- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient

Comment: The first one and second are the same and it has problem running in React Native