# How to call a webservice method for testing, e.g. from a browser

Tags: web-services, delphi, dll, service

There is a dll webservice (made with Delphi) that has a method called *List* which returns a list of strings (widestring).

Is there any method for calling that service without having to write a client application for consuming it?.

Ex.: http://misitio.com:8080/miwebservice.dll?methodname=list

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to call methods in the ws without writing a client application? Can't you do that by using a browser or maybe even curl?

Comment: you must use an application like SOAP UI or equivalents.

Comment: You have to describe more about how the webservice is built.  For instance, if it was built with DataSnap and HTTP support, then you can use a web browser to call any of the methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post a SOAP request from a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886153/how-to-post-a-soap-request-from-a-browser)

Answer (score 12):

The Chrome App [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) can send SOAP requests. You just need to provide the Web Service URL, select POST, set the proper content-type header (text/xml, application/soap+xml, etc.), and provide the proper xml soap body in the request.  Click Send.

Below is an example request which posts to a [free weather web service](http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?op=GetCityWeatherByZIP).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your request could be something like:

```
POST /WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityWeatherByZIP HTTP/1.1
Host: wsf.cdyne.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e5bc46a4-71ac-f357-78a7-c4b4de894afb
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

ZIP=90210
```

And the response will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WeatherReturn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
  <Success>true</Success>
  <ResponseText>City Found</ResponseText>
  <State>CA</State>
  <City>Beverly Hills</City>
  <WeatherStationCity>Van Nuys</WeatherStationCity>
  <WeatherID>4</WeatherID>
  <Description>Sunny</Description>
  <Temperature>68</Temperature>
  <RelativeHumidity>54</RelativeHumidity>
  <Wind>CALM</Wind>
  <Pressure>29.89R</Pressure>
  <Visibility />
  <WindChill />
  <Remarks />
</WeatherReturn>
```