# Ability to call a soap web service from a browser

Tags: web-services, soap

I need to clarify some problems regarding soap web services.

1) can I call a soap web service by just typing the url of the endpoint in the browser?

2) does the answer for question  depend on what type of technologies used to develop the soap web service?

If I need to invoke a soap web service, i need to send a soap request. But by just sending a **get** or **post** request from a browser cannot generate a soap request. so by default I shouldn't be able to invoke a soap web service just using the browser.

but the following two resources are contradicting above assumptions of mine.Can someone explain me how these soap web services can be invoked without a soap request?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719483%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-to-call-web-service-from-browser

Comment: You can call SOAP methods from browser only if it accept as parameters only basic types (string, int, bool and so on).

Comment: does that mean i don't need a soap envelop to invoke a soap web service?

Comment: Still need an envelope, and the browser can support it
But you can call to it with a Postman from Chrome anyway -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924351/how-to-call-a-webservice-method-for-testing-e-g-from-a-browser

Comment: And for IIS you can call to methods of SOAP service only locally on machine where it installed like it shown  here - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94043/SOAP-Web-Services-Create-Once-Consume-Everywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post a SOAP request from a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886153/how-to-post-a-soap-request-from-a-browser)