# How to view soap service data from my browser

Tags: c#, web-services, google-chrome, internet-explorer, soap

I'm completely new to how soap services work, please correct me if my understanding is wrong. I would like to pass parameters and call a function from a soap service by typing in a url on my browser (Chrome) and then would like to see the results. I tried searching and following the information from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719483(v=vs.71).aspx), but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have tried the following variations:

```
http://<servername>/apppath/MyService.asmx?op=GetData?loc=01&status=OPEN

http://<servername>/apppath/MyService.asmx/GetData?loc=01&status=OPEN
```

This is what I get when I go to the url.

```
http:/<servername>/apppath/MyService.asmx?op=GetData?
```

[image]
Please help.

Comment: The input to a SOAP call is xml. The outer xml (SOAP envelope) and the inner xml (the data). The response from the SOAP call will also be xml. Depending on how the SOAP service is set up, you may be able to navigate to the wsdl and see examples of the SOAP input xml and output xml.

Comment: Not sure you can do this by typing it in the url, the SOAP method will expect the input xml as the body of the request.

Comment: access soap web services through URL ?

Comment: Is there a tool (such as a chrome app/plugin) that would allow me to see what I'm trying to accomplish? I tried Postman for Chrome but Im not sure if I'm just using it incorrectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post a SOAP request from a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886153/how-to-post-a-soap-request-from-a-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error was my understanding of **SOAP** and host to use **Postman**. In short, *I wasn't able to accomplish a SOAP request through the browser*. Also, the picture supplied, it showed I was missing 2 things. 1) The `SoapAction` 2) The parameters were not supplied in the url but rather in the `<soap:Body>` tag. These were supplied in the POST and I was able to view my results in **Postman**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are requesting wrong urls? If you have .asmx in your application - you should be able to see the description page on the url

> http://{servername}/{apppath}/MyService.asmx

Of course you should replace **{servername}** the **{apppath}** with your values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send an HTTP POST request in order to call your web service GetData.

Your JS code should be something like:

```
//url should be MyService.asmx/GetData
function callWS(url) {
    var loc = "01";
    var status = "OPEN";

    var options = { error: function(msg) { alert(msg.d); },
                    type: "POST", url: "webmethods.aspx/UpdatePage",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ loc: loc, status: status }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true, 
                    success: function(response) { alert(response); } 
                  }; 

    $.ajax(options);
}
```

Comment: I believe that's what I have? Does the screenshot I've included above confirm this?

Comment: what happens if you try http://<servername>/apppath/MyService.asmx/GetData?loc=01&status=OPEN ?

Comment: I get an exception: `Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetData'`

Comment: ok, it makes sense. you have to send a HTTP POST to call the web service.

Comment: Is there a tool that I can use that would help me accomplish this? I know how to do via C#, but I was hoping that there exists something in which I can just type the function call and a a result. I also tried `http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html` but I'm unsure how to use it in my case.

Comment: Ah. You can try to use Postman (if you use chrome) or RESTClient (in case of firefox).