# SOAP via Website without JavaScript (but with ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, mobile, soap, web-applications

How can I access a SOAP endpoint and do requests via a website without using JavaScript. My favorite solution would be an ASP.NET web app with C#. I am trying to figure out for several days now, but I am not generating progress to be honest. I'd be glad if you could give me some hints or good links. Thank you.

Comment: Download SOAP UI and try to learn something about it :) it's good for testing... And why SOAP and not REST?

Comment: The SOAP endpoint is already existing for a long time now. The requests are ready to use, but I can't find out how to do so via a website without javascript...

Comment: Well, so as i said... download [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) and test it there.

Comment: I already did. But my question is how to bring them to my website now, so I can do the requests from any device just by calling the website

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065577/how-to-view-soap-service-data-from-my-browser