# How to call SOAP API from the browser

Tags: google-chrome, soap, browser

I have a localhost SOAP API that I can call using Chrome's extension [Boomerang - SOAP & REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boomerang-soap-rest-clien/eipdnjedkpcnlmmdfdkgfpljanehloah/reviews) it works and I get results with this request:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eko="http://localhost:8080/api/myapi.wsdl">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <eko:getReview>
            <eko:auth>123abfdbgfdg</eko:auth>
            <eko:changed_since>2016-06-07</eko:changed_since>
            <eko:rating_id>?</eko:rating_id>
            <eko:product_id>?</eko:product_id>
        </eko:getReview>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

Now I need to call this API method; getReview, using the browser. So I tried to pass those parameters like this:

```
http://localhost/api/api.php/getReview/123abfdbgfdg/2016-06-07
```

But seems not working: I just get back the WSDL service help, but not the actual call results.

Is it even possible to call SOAP from browser?

Comment: check if this helps - http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-to-call-web-service-from-browser

Comment: already checked it. but thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post a SOAP request from a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886153/how-to-post-a-soap-request-from-a-browser)