# How to add custom header to ASMX web service call using jquery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, asmx, soapheader

I have a web service with the following contract:

```
POST /Service/service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "xxx.xxx.xxx/Service/Method"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Request xmlns="xxx.xxx.xxx/Service/">
      <transactiontype>string</transactiontype>
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
    </Request>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <Method xmlns="xxx.xxx.xxx/Service/">
      <xml>xml</xml>
    </Method>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I am trying to call the service using jquery. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: serverUrl + 'Method',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: { xml: "xml" },
    beforeSend: function (req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Header', '<Request xmlns="xxx.xxx.xxx/Service/">'
                            +'<transactiontype>4</transactiontype>'
                            +'<agencyName>name</agencyName>'
                            +'<username>user</username>'
                            +'<password>pass</password>'
                            +'</Request>');                    
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.text);
    },
    error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
        alert(status);
    }
});
```

However, the header content is not passed to the web service? How would I go about passing the header credentials to my web service call?

Comment: Please show how the header is defined in the service. Also, are you able to pass the header using a C# client program?

Comment: Are you sure that XML stuff is supposed to be a "header"? From the "contract" it looks just like the payload. Note: `soap:Header` (just an element in the XML) has *nothing* to do with HTTP headers.

Comment: <soap:Header>
    <Request xmlns="xxx.xxx.xxx/Service/">
      <transactiontype>string</transactiontype>
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
    </Request>
  </soap:Header> 
Is what I get from the WSDL. How would I check how the header is defined? I just want to know how would I pass in the user credentials to the soap-based web service

Comment: @Mike Read my comment again :-) `setRequestHeader` is at the HTTP-level. Not related to `soap:Header`. The HTTP-header you may need to specify is `SOAPAction`. This is only required for SOAP 1.x, IIRC, and can be omitted for SOAP 2.x (which makes it more browser-friendly).

Comment: @pst so then how would I pass the username and password to the web service call?

Comment: @Mike Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript -- the first answer has an example. Look at what "headers" are set, and where.

Answer (score 1):

[`soap:Header`](http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_header.asp) is an XML element inside the XML/SOAP data "payload". This is different than an [HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). In the contract, `SOAPAction` (along with `Content-Length`, etc) is an HTTP header.

`XmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader` is used for specifying HTTP headers. It has nothing to do with anything inside the XML (directly).

The first answer at [Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript) should give an example of how to make a SOAP request. Note:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetQuote");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
...
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<soap:Envelope...' + etc;
xmlhttp.send(xml)
```

It is the XML which contains `soap:Envelope` and the child elements `soap:Header` and `soap:Body`.

Happy coding.