# Consume ASP .Net WebService using HTML AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I am trying to call a simple hellowworld function of ASP .NET WebService using JQuery AJAX call written in separate HTML file i.e. Not aspx file in ASP .NET.
Here is code of my AJAX call which works fine in aspx based web client.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Test1/RSSReader.asmx/GetRSSReader",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#output").text(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#output").html("WebSerivce error " + e.responseText);
            }
        });
```

I want to call same webservice and same method using .html file but it is returning error. I tried giving server address i.e. localhost but still no response.

Comment: error means it execute ERROR block of AJAX not success also there is no value in e.responseText. i.e. it just shows  "WebSerivce error ".

Comment: Are you sure , you are returning JSON format data , and make user your webservice works independently via fiddler or postman rest client in chrome or any other tool.

Comment: Is the "separate HTML file" from where the ajax is called hosted in the same application? If not, it might be a "Same origin policy" issue.

Comment: No it is not hosted in same location but that is  the point i want to call webservice remotely

Comment: You are right when i copy HTML to same application which have webservice it works fine. But i want to call webservice remotely. i.e. separate client and server locations.

Comment: Then you have to implement CORS:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/
and take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536139/how-to-add-custom-header-to-asmx-web-service-call-using-jquery?rq=1