# Calling WSDL Service via jQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services, wsdl

I've been googling for something to call WSDL (SOAP) based service using jQuery but I don't find anything.

Is there really a way to call them like I call REST based services?

The example URL I have is http://sub.domain.com/j/services/ivos?wsdl

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of this call? WSDL is just XML, so you should be able to parse it. But what do you want to do afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u can modify the header sent to your wsdl i guess its possible.

Comment: to get the results from a wsdl, u need to send a specifik header request. Example on a soap request :         POST/BibleWebservice.asmx HTTP/1.1"
                   Host: www.webservicex.net
                   Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
                   http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetBookTitles. if u are able to modify the header jquery is sending to  the wsdl, i guess u will get the right result back,

Comment: actually the Service is created via Visual Studio by some guy and I am not sure how can I utilize it. Can you post some link for me to read about SOAP based services as when I point to the ?wsdl link it has huge XML in it?

Comment: a soap envelope need also to be included

Comment: its the the required xml (function name, paramters etc) thats need to be sent to a wsdl,  a wsdl does always have instructions on how the SOAP envelop should look like example:  http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_envelope.asp,

Comment: Now I realized. I think the question should how to create SOAP Envelope using WSDL response XML?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the stack overflow question [Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript) if that's what you need

Although I am unsure what you need to do ?wsdl will just send the webservice description in xml form.

The way I would tackle this would be to create a rest wrapper that takes care of the soap handling and sends json responses.

This way you can call it using $.ajax, $.getJSON, $.post etc

Comment: No the services are already written via SOAP. I just want to know the way to call them using JS. Any way you know?

Comment: No, I am sure there are libraries to do that, I just meant that it will probably be easier to wrap it server side.