# Jquery WebService

Tags: jquery, web-services, javascript

I'm trying to get any data from public webservice http://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx?WSDL
but something goes wrong with it. Every time I get "0 error" failure alert message. Can anybody help with it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="hello" value="Get data."/>
<script>
    $("#hello").click(function () {
                $.support.cors = true;
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "http://www.cbr.ru/DailyInfoWebServ/DailyInfo.asmx/EnumValutes",
                data: "{Seld : False}",
                datatype: "xml",
                success: function (msg)
                {
                   Successfullcalling(msg);
                },
                error: Failurecalling
            });
    });

    function Successfullcalling(res)
    {
        alert("Done!");
    }
    function Failurecalling(res)
     {
       alert(res.status + ' ' + res.statusText);
     } 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possibly duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551423/calling-wsdl-service-via-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is a cross domain request. 
On which domain work you'r script?

Comment: Domain is different from mine, but I think that $.support.cors = true; should help with it.

Comment: I think you should also set crossDomain to true (it is by default false)

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you should send as data not "{Seld : False}", but {"Seld" : false} or {"Seld" : "False"}.

Comment: I think it is a different problem with it, because when I try invoke a method without params and I get the same result "0 and error".

Comment: I will try to find a different solution for this problem. I also found this "note that many browsers do not allow cross-domain calls for security reasons" may be it is a reason of the problem.

Comment: I tried to make such query on site. There is no problem with crossDomain. I got every time 302 code. So somethings is not ok with url.
P.S. You should send {"Seld" : false} or {"Seld" : "False"} (I don't know exactly) But I'm sure that not "{Seld : False}".
Also you should set up crossDomain to true.

Answer (score 0):

as Boris has said in his reply this is the problem of cross domain request

have a look at this

[jQuery Ajax - Status Code 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0)