# access webservice wsdl from jquery

Tags: jquery, web-services, wsdl

Are there any examples that i can find to know access `wsdl` operations from the `jquery`? i got an `wsdl` with 3 operations on it. (add , update , delete) how can i pass the parameters for these operations from the `jquery`? is there any specific way to do that? Appreciate your guidance. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the web service is not running on the same origin (host:port) as your site it won't work due to same-origin-policy. You can use a serverside script (PHP, Python, etc.) to proxy the requests though.

If the origins are the same, have a look at [Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. yes in my case origins are the same. i am new to webservice technology and i am wondering how can i get the operations that i need to access and pass the parameters to them. according to the example shall i access my service like this `http://localhost:8080/test.asmx?op=Add' and another question i am wondering is how can i pass parameters. i need to pass `testName(String)` & `testId(int)` as parameters. appreciate your help.

Comment: I found a solution and i need to access server side proxies to access the webservice. that is because of the domain issue. when service is on domain 1 and my jsp works on domain 2 `XMLHttpRequest` object will never allow me to access the webservice. (security concerns). so that i need to get the back end webservice access to retrieve the results from the service.

Comment: What happens if i used an Iframe? is this possible? ( access cross domain web service from a java script)