# How to use Web service in Google Gadgets (using Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, soap, google-gadget

Have you ever tried to call a SOAP web service from a google gadget using javascript ?
I really don't know how to do it : the API has just a makerequest method.
Is it the right method to get the job done ?

I would appreciate any help...

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi this existing solution has what your looking for

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript