# is it possible to do SOAP Xml parsing through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lot of SO  Answers are saying that SOAP webservice is not good using javascript.but the following [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)   tells that it is possible.butis it possible through jquery using cross domain policy in for SOAP? any help please? I am working on HTML5 with javascript for mobiles,not in server side.

Comment: Well yes, you'd just use $.post to send some XML through to the .asmx page... why do you need to use jQuery/Javascript? Cant you just use cURL? Please explain  the question a bit better...

Comment: I have edited my question, what is cURL, is it possible to use in mobile as client side?

Comment: cURL is PHP, see below answer by Kyle, thats a good response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery does have a SOAP project you can use, if you are interested.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient

It is currently in beta, but it will get the job done.

Comment: is it possible cross domain policy through this without server side proxy, for example XML Parsing?

Comment: Dead link :-(
They shuttered the site.