# how to call soap web service from regular html with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, soap

im trying to call a webservice from a simple `.html` site.

what im trying to do is a post action so im send a string parameter to the webmethod without trying to get a result back. Can i do this or is this even possible without working with a framework like .net or php

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Using the XMLHttpRequest object (standard JavaScript), you'd construct the standard SOAP envelope around your XML message. [Here is an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP#Example_message) of the envelope. You'd then want to use a POST, not a GET to send it.

It would be a good idea to download a SOAP utility like SOAPUI to help you debug it.