# Get the SOAP response from server

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap, soapui, soap-client

I tried to make the SOAP call according to the
[Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)

I am able to send the request through this code but there is no response coming from the server. The sample code i given below:

enter code here

```
<html>



   <head>
     <title>SOAP call sample</title>
     <script language="Javascript">
     <!--     

     function xmlhttpPost() {
      var symbol = "MSFT";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?op=GetQuote",true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

 if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {

     alert("ready state callback:"+xmlhttp.readyState);

     alert("response text or XML"xmlhttp.responseText);

     var json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(xmlhttp.responseXML);

  var result = json.Body[0].GetQuoteResponse[0].GetQuoteResult[0].Text;

  json = XMLObjectifier.xmlToJSON(XMLObjectifier.textToXML(result));

  alert(symbol + ' Stock Quote: $' + json.Stock[0].Last[0].Text); 

 }

}


xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetQuote");

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("POST","/stockquote.asmx HTTP/1.1");

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Host","www.webservicex.net");

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length",1000);

alert("setrequest header completed");

var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
 '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
                'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
                'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' + 
   '<soap:Body> ' +
     '<GetQuote xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/"> ' +
       '<symbol>' + symbol + '</symbol> ' +
     '</GetQuote> ' +
   '</soap:Body> ' +
 '</soap:Envelope>';

xmlhttp.send(xml);

alert("request sent"+xmlhttp);

     }
//-->
  </script>

</head>

<form name="main">

  <table>

     <tr>

       <td> <input value="Submit to eBay => " type="button" 
onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost()'></td>
       <td><textarea name="eBayXMLResponse" wrap="soft" rows="40" cols="50" style="overflow:scroll" ID="Textarea1"></textarea></td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </form>

</html>
```

I tried this sample with dynamic web project through eclipse and running through apache-tomcat-7.0.25 app server.Is this enough to run this sample? 
Please help me to display the response in the browser console.
i am struggling for a week in this issue..... please let me know if anybody has idea about this.

Comment: Maybe you need a packet capture between the client and the server, to see what happened.

Comment: hi ciphor, please tell me clearly what is required to get SOAP response?

Comment: There are multiple possible reasons, 1. the request is not sent out; 2. the server is not working; 3. the response is not sent out; the packet capture would help you to clarify which situation you've met.

Comment: can you tell me how to implement  the packet capture in this sample?

Comment: the callback function  return the xmlhttp.readyState as 4 i.e. request finished and response is ready.but in my code the xmlhttp.responseXML value is showing as NULL.

Comment: when the callback function is getting called, the xmlhttp.responseXML is NULL.but the readystate returning the value as 4(request finished and response is ready.)

Comment: you can use the software "wireshark" to capture the packet between client and server

Comment: this wireshark what it will do?

Comment: Actually, from your comments, I got the information that the client received the response but failed to parse it, is it correct?

Comment: ya correct.                                                                   i used the wireshark . it is working. it is capturing the network packet.the status i given below                                                                                   3403 1381.157522 192.168.0.149 192.168.0.4 DNS 79     Standard query A www.webservicex.net                                                                     3405 1381.868253 192.168.0.4 192.168.0.149 DNS 109 Standard query response CNAME webservicex.net A 173.201.44.188

Comment: please give an idea to display the data on browser console. Please see my above code and according to that give your suggestion.

Comment: Did the line "alert("ready state callback:"+xmlhttp.readyState);" printed out?

Comment: Then at which line did it go wrong?

Comment: alert(xmlhttp.responseText) is returning nothing. if we put alert(xmlhttp.responseXML) it is returning NULL.

Comment: one more thing i want to add as : xmlHttpReq.status is returning 0. actually if the request is processed successfully it should return 200 and if the page is not found means the status value should be 404 but it is returning 0

Comment: ciphor, when i connect my host machine into our domain this code is working on Internet explorer but it is not working on other browsers like safari and firefox... please suggest to make this work on cross domain if you know....

Answer (score 0):

try making the soap request using jquery. This works for me:

```
var soapAction = this.Namespace + this.Contract + '/' + pMethod;
var soapResponse = pMethod + 'Response', soapResult = pMethod + 'Result';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: this.URI,
    data: envelope,
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);
    },
    success: function (pData) {
        var answer;
        $(pData).find(soapResponse).each(function () {
            answers=this.parseResult(($(this).find(soapResult))[0]);
        });
        onSuccess(answers);
    },
    error: onError
});
```