# How to upload an image from mobile web app (PhoneGap & JavaScript) to a SOAP web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap, jquery-mobile, cordova

How do you send images from a mobile web app to an existing web service. I considered using the [PhoneGap FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) object, but I don't know how to wrap the call in a SOAP packet.

The server where I need to upload the image, expects the image to wrapped in a SOAP packet. From the service description below, one can see that the server expects the file in base64Binary. Has anyone done something like this before, or am I the first (or last) buffalo to cross the river (to get eaten by a crocodile):

```
POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <AuthHeader xmlns="http://localhost/">
      <LogonID>string</LogonID>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </AuthHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <uploadFile xmlns="http://localhost/">
      <FileDetails>
        <ReferenceNumber>string</ReferenceNumber>
        <FileName>string</FileName>
        <FileType>int</FileType>
        <FileContents>base64Binary</FileContents>
      </FileDetails>
    </uploadFile>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsajax/) on how to call SOAP webservices from javascript.
and [here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) for base64 encoding files

Comment: That's really a great answer, have you ever tried sending a SOAP request with mtom attachment using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

May not be the direct solution as you are looking for but following example might work for you.

http://www.javascriptbank.com/javascript/article/ajax/simple-ajax-file-uploader/preview/en/

Also this SOW thread has list of alternatives to call webservice from javascript.

[Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to upload an image directly from JavaScript to a SOAP web service - it was becoming too much of a hack.

I solved the problem by developing gateway to act as a filter between the mobile app and the web service. The gateway filters out image upload requests and extracts the base64 encoded image sent by a PhoneGap FileTransfer object. It then converts this into a base64binary array as expected by the web service.

It is just much more flexible this way, than to try and do everything in JavaScript.