# How to handle XML response data of a Web-Service in JavaScript using JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services

I am a newbie to handle XML response data. I have a web service which checks the user and his password in SQL server database and return the response accordingly. Code as follows for the web service method;

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function Authentication(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As String

        'Public Function ConnectToSQL() As String
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim result As Boolean
        Dim response As String

        Try

            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TestServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myuser;Password=mypass"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT username FROM user_detail WHERE username='" + username  + "' AND password='" + password + "'", con)
            con.Open()


            ' Execute Query
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            result = reader.HasRows
        'Validate user info from database 
           If result = True Then
            response = "Valid user info..Thanks"
        Else
            response = " Not valid user info..Please Enter again, Thanks"
        End If

        If Not reader Is Nothing Then
            reader.Close()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server." & ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close() 'Whether there is error or not. Close the connection.
        End Try
        Return response 
    End Function
End Class
```

The response is in XML data as shown in following fig.(if entered valid user info)

[image: Valid Response]

Now I want to make a view in Javascript, which take input from user and then validate user infor from database via this web service. Can some one help me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a form that can accept username and password

and submit to your web service using javascript SOAP client.So you need to make  SOAP request and pass username and password to that service where it validates .You can see examples for consuming web service is using javascript here.

[Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)

http://www.guru4.net/articoli/javascript-soap-client/en/

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any other way to handle this? I mean other than SOAP Client?

Comment: you can access it using REST in javascript