# How to call .NET WSDL call in jQuery Javascript?

Tags: jquery, wsdl, webserver

I have one web service built in .NET SOAP. URLlike http://.../abc.asmx?WSDL

In that i have one function called abc.

So how can i call that webservice because it not directly return me XML.

In WSDL i have to call function then it return me XML file.

Tried using

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://...asmx?WSDL',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
           alert(xml);

   },
    error: function(xhr, xml) { alert('else'+xml + '\n' + xhr.responseText); }
  });
```

but it send me to error not success

Comment: Take a good read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), specify the URL, and the data type

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourPage.aspx/yourWebSerivice/YourMethod",
  type: "POST",
  data: "{}",
  dataType: "xml"
});
```

Comment: So it is so easy ? well, I've wasted a couple of year fliyng through envelopes, security headers and cross domain stuffs for nothing... - just joking pal, this example shows only how to perform an ajax post, not a SOAP call.