# javascript and web services WSDL

Tags: javascript, wsdl

i want to call a web service using javascript. i have a form where i give some parameters (int) and want to get the result how can do it using javascript?

here are the WSDL files

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://lapack.sws4hpsc.uth/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://lapack.sws4hpsc.uth/" name="DgesvSampleWsService">
<ns1:Policy xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" wsu:Id="DgesvSampleWsPortBinding_MTOM_Policy">
<ns1:ExactlyOne>
<ns1:All>
<ns2:OptimizedMimeSerialization xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" ns1:Optional="true"/>
</ns1:All>
</ns1:ExactlyOne>
</ns1:Policy>
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://lapack.sws4hpsc.uth/" schemaLocation="http://83.212.96.238:8080/DgesvSampleWs/DgesvSampleWsService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="_dgesv">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:_dgesv"/>
</message>
<message name="_dgesvResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:_dgesvResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="DgesvSampleWs">
<operation name="_dgesv">
<input message="tns:_dgesv"/>
<output message="tns:_dgesvResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="DgesvSampleWsPortBinding" type="tns:DgesvSampleWs">
<ns3:PolicyReference xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" URI="#DgesvSampleWsPortBinding_MTOM_Policy"/>
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="_dgesv">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="DgesvSampleWsService">
<port name="DgesvSampleWsPort" binding="tns:DgesvSampleWsPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://83.212.96.238:8080/DgesvSampleWs/DgesvSampleWsService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

---

and the second one

```
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://lapack.sws4hpsc.uth/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://lapack.sws4hpsc.uth/" name="DgtsvSampleWsService">
<ns1:Policy xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" wsu:Id="DgtsvSampleWsPortBinding_MTOM_Policy">
<ns1:ExactlyOne>
<ns1:All>
<ns2:OptimizedMimeSerialization xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy/optimizedmimeserialization" ns1:Optional="true"/>
</ns1:All>
</ns1:ExactlyOne>
</ns1:Policy>
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://lapack.sws4hpsc.uth/" schemaLocation="http://83.212.96.238:8080/DgtsvSampleWs/DgtsvSampleWsService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="_dgtsv">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:_dgtsv"/>
</message>
<message name="_dgtsvResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:_dgtsvResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="DgtsvSampleWs">
<operation name="_dgtsv">
<input message="tns:_dgtsv"/>
<output message="tns:_dgtsvResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="DgtsvSampleWsPortBinding" type="tns:DgtsvSampleWs">
<ns3:PolicyReference xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" URI="#DgtsvSampleWsPortBinding_MTOM_Policy"/>
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<operation name="_dgtsv">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="DgtsvSampleWsService">
<port name="DgtsvSampleWsPort" binding="tns:DgtsvSampleWsPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://83.212.96.238:8080/DgtsvSampleWs/DgtsvSampleWsService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here a possible approach, assuming you put wsdl into a file `request.wsdl` and assuming that the remote server is accessible and have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header

```
//wsdl request
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', 'request.wsdl');
client.onreadystatechange = function () {
  var request = client.responseText;//here the wsdl

        //SOAP request
        var client2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client2.open('POST', 'http://83.212.96.238:8080/DgesvSampleWs/DgesvSampleWsService', true);

        client2.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (client2.readyState == 4) {
            if (client2.status == 200) {
              console.log(client.responseText);//here the response
            }
          }
        }
        client2.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        client2.send(request);
}

client.send();
```

The idea is performing and ajax to call wsdl definitions and in it's callback, perform another ajax that call that you want to call. This domains `http://83.212.96.238:808` it's not giving me response but I think the approach is valid.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a SOAP request and invoke the caller.
   **ref:** [Simplest SOAP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example)
2. Get the response and parse the XML.
   **ref:** [Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)