# parse xml data by traversing through each node in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse the below xml data by traversing through each node.

```
<example>
<name>BlueWhale</name>
<addr>101 Yesler Way, Suite 402</addr>
<city>Seattle</city>
<state>Washington</state>
</example>
```

Now I want to access each node without doing getElementsByTagName and print each NodeName & NodeValue in javascript, with the help of things like, rootElement,firstchild,nextSibling which i am not sure of.

I am trying the following manner

```
var txt = " <example>  <name>BlueWhale</name> <addr>101 Yesler Way, Suite 402</addr>  <city>Seattle</city>  <state>Washington</state>  </example> "
var domParser = new DOMParser();
xml = domParser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
var el =xml.documentElement.nodeName;
console.log(el);
```

and print each var.
Could anyone please help.

Comment: Would you consider using library that would do parsing for you?

Comment: check this http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, however 1) I don prefer using jQuery 2) I do not prefer doing it by getElementsByTagName, as while implementing it, xml data received is dynamic hence i wish to access each of it by position and not by tag name.

Answer (score 1):

if you xml is stored inside a string variable you can use jQuery.

```
var xml = "<example>...";

$(xml).children().each(function() {
    var tagName = this.tagName;
    var text = this.innerHtml
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using library that does that for you rather than doing it by hand. One of commonly used one's [you can find here.](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/)