# Extract immediate child of a tag in XML string without any libraries

Tags: xml, regex, parsing, xml-parsing

Say I have the below xml string :

```
<root>  
 <a>  
     <c>  </c>
 </a>

 <b>  </b>

</root>
```

Say i want **immediate children** of 'root' my approach :

1. Extract tags inside root by using regex:

   **extractedString = myXmlString.match(/<(\w+)([^>]*)>([\s\S]*)</\1>/g)[3]**
2. use a regex to get the child tags , but it gives me all the children i use this regex on the extracted string (i.e. the string between the root tags)

   **childArray = extractedString.match(/<\w+/g)**

but the above one also returns me **c**  which is obvious , is there any way of extracting only **a** and **b** . or is this approach wrong? I am not looking forward to use any library please do correct me if my approach is wrong towards this (i.e. using regex) and suggest the correct way of doing this.

Comment: What is the language you are using? If it is JS, this post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript

Comment: It might be possible to do it by checking for a single TAB at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I am using javascript true but I do not want to use DOM parser am just trying this out as an exercise. So I want to know about the approach and code behind it.

Comment: @RishulMatta: If you are not using the DOM parser, then you are left with the option of reinventing the wheel or write a brittle regex that can break at the slightest change.

Comment: any pointer will be helpful so please suggest the correct way of dealing with it , should i write my own parser? what sources can i refer ? etc etc pls help