# How to get the text value of an XML node in IE8?

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-8, nodes

So I have an XML feed that returns a bunch of results. First I create an XML parser as [outlined in faino's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript).

The XML parses just fine. Every result looks like this:

```
<result>
 <title>some title</title>
 <bid>0.05123</bid>
 <description>some desc</description>
</result>
```

So I have:

```
// parse
var xmlParser = returnXMLParser();
var resultsDoc = xmlParser(adXML.responseData); // #document
var listings = resultsDoc.getElementsByTagName('listing'); // returns 8-10
// get title node
var title = listings[0].getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
title.nodeType // 1
title.nodeName // "title"
```

Here's the problem though, I have tried every property imaginable to get the inner text: `textConent`, `innerText`, `innerHTML`, `nodeValue` - none of them seem to work in IE8.

The same script works perfectly fine in Chrome / FF using `.textContent`

Help!

Comment: Try `title.childNodes[0].nodeValue`

Comment: Another textNode inside? Bah, that was a waste of 20 minutes...

Comment: title.text should do it in IE8

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery for this? It should provide a cross-browser way to parse that XML and `$(node).text()` should get you the nodes' text content just fine.

Comment: @JLRishe Unfortunately, can't use jQuery for this project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cross-browser backwards-compatible script:

```
function getXMLContent(obj,action)
{

    //cross-browser get and set for xmlContent
    if (obj)
    {
        if (action == "get") //get
        {
            if(obj.textContent)
            {
                return obj.textContent;
            }
            else
            {
                return obj.text;
            }
        }
        else //set
        {
            if(obj.textContent)
            {
                obj.textContent = action;
            }
            else
            {
                obj.text = action;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Error("XML-Element doesn't exist.");
    }
}
```

In my own AJAX-calls where I retrieve XML I always use this function to retrieve to content of the node.