# Parsing XML into a new Element when a new XML node is added issues

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

So what I'm trying to do is parse XML data into a new DIV which has an ID of post, this will happen each time a post is added to the XML file (posts.xml).

I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something, but I can't get the XML Data to display/render.

**XML:**

```
<POSTS>
    <POST>
        <TITLE>Title 123</TITLE>
        <AUTHOR>Bob Dylan</AUTHOR>
        <CONTENT>BLAH BLAH BLAH</CONTENT>
    </POST>
<POSTS>
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="posts"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript (main.js):**

```
  (function () {

  // Adds a DOM structure for each post.
  function renderPosts(posts) {

    // Get the DOM element that will contain the posts.
    var postsDiv = document.getElementById("posts");

    posts.forEach(function (post) {

      // Create the DOM elements.
      var postDiv = document.createElement("div"),
          postTitleDiv = document.createElement("div"),
          postAuthorDiv = document.createElement("div"),
          postContentDiv = document.createElement("div");

      // Set the content of each element.
      postNameDiv.innerHTML = post.name;
      postAuthorDiv.innerHTML = post.author;
      postContentDiv.innerHTML = post.content;

      // Set CSS classes on each div so they can be styled.
      postDiv.setAttribute("class", "post");
      postNameDiv.setAttribute("class", "post-title");
      postAuthorDiv.setAttribute("class", "post-author");
      postContentDiv.setAttribute("class", "post-content");

      // Assemble the post div.
      postDiv.appendChild(postTitleDiv);
      postDiv.appendChild(postAuthorDiv);
      postDiv.appendChild(postContentDiv);

      // Add the post div to the container for posts.
      postsDiv.appendChild(postDiv);
    });
  }

  // Fetches the file "posts.xml"
  function getPosts(callback){

    // Fetch the xml file using XMLHttpRequest.
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // When the file has loaded,
    request.onload = function () {

      // parse the XML text into an array of post objects.
      //var posts = XML.parse(request.responseXML);

      // Pass the posts array to the callback.
      callback(posts);
    };
    request.open("GET", "posts.xml", false);
    request.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 
  }

  // The main program, which gets then renders posts.
  getPosts(function (posts) {
    renderPosts(posts);
  });

}()); //End Main Function
```

Comment: Where are you getting XML.parse from? This is not a browser provided API. This is throwing a JavaScript error that stops your script from doing anything with the data. `posts` is undefined because of that.

Comment: If you want to make this easy, the data should be JSON, so you could use JSON.parse. Otherwise, you need to parse the XML manually using DOMParser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript