# how to convert .net service response to string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

i get this response form web service in my java script.

> < string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
>   $,100559,11:05,22.298953,70.795753,# < string>

how to get this string to simply string as mention below.

I want string like this : `$,100559,11:05,22.298953,70.795753,#`

Comment: i want to convert response object to string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Javascript based solution for converting xml to string and vice versa :

```
function StringToXML(oString) {
//code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
var oXML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"); oXML.loadXML(oString);
return oXML;
}
// code for Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else {
return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(oString, "text/xml");
}
}

function XMLToString(oXML)
{
//code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
var oString = oXML.xml; return oString;
}
// code for Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else {
return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(oXML);
}
}
```

Comment: for this solution i required any library or jar file?

Comment: No, this is pure javascript.

Comment: this error occurred when i am using this method: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': Invalid node value.