# MPD Parsing with JS

Tags: javascript, mpeg-dash, mpd

I want to parse **Media Presentation Description** (MPD) file with a library using the Javascript language. Are there libraries or a library that permit me to parse simply MPD file ? I saw *dashif library*, but this is hard to use. I don't want player ! I want only parse the informations in MPD file and use these to make my script for display them.

Comment: The **MPD** file is an XML so any available XML parser will do. Or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: @aergistal I tried to make a MPD parser with JS, but this is expensive in terms of time. I believe that if I can use a mpd parser already done from another source(for example dashif), and use that to parse mpd file, i'll spend less work instead of to make it from zero.

Comment: You need an XML parser. See [Parse XML using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript). If you're using node.js then there are XML parser modules available such as `xml2js`, `xml-parser` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about a JavaScript tool that it's only focus is to parse the file, however Google has a HTML 5 dash player that is more focused than Dash if, which might make it simpler to make use of just their manifest parsing.

https://github.com/google/shaka-player