# React-Native fetch XML data

Tags: javascript, xml, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React-Native. Trying to make some very simple apps. Can't figure out how to fetch XML data. With JSON everything is clear and simple.

But how to fetch XML? Tried to convert it to JSON via [this](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/) and some other similar scripts, but without any success. Need help :/

My code looks very simple:

```
var xml_url = 'http://api.example.com/public/all.xml';

var ExampleProject = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: {results:{}},
    };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  fetchData: function() {
    fetch(xml_url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          data: responseData.data,
        });
      })
      .done();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.box}>
            <Text style={styles.heading}>Heading</Text>
            <Text>Some text</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: Try using `response.text()`

Comment: Any answer on this? I've run into the same problem. Is there no pure JS XML parser out there?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can try https://github.com/connected-lab/react-native-xml2js ,

```
    const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;

    fetch('link')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            parseString(response, function (err, result) {
                console.log(response)
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('fetch', err)
        })
```

I use it to my project.

Comment: As of Feb, 2019 this answer still appears to be the most relevant.  You may want to switch to ES6 import syntax instead though to keep up with current conventions: import { parseString } from "react-native-xml2js";

Comment: newb question, after npm install react-native-xml2js, I get "Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native-xml2js' in '/Users/me/firsttry/src/components'" when I use that import.

Answer (score 5):

you can use **npm install xmldom**, now load DOMParser as below :

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser
```

I use it to my project.

Comment: Has anyone tried to use xmldom specifically in React Native?

Comment: I use it in my demo project. you can refer to the  demo https://github.com/kaich/ASReact/blob/master/App/Main/TypePage.js

Comment: Does it support both Android and iOS?

Comment: @LawGimenez Today I just used xmldom to process an RSS feed. I'm still in the early stages but it seems to work fine with iOS and Android.

Answer (score 2):

First of all - React Native using `JavaScriptCore`, which is just a javascript interpreter, so no Browser Object Model, no document object, no window, etc. That's a reason why you cannot use `DOMParser` for example.

Indeed React provides you a [XMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/Network) wrapper, but it doesn't include `responseXML`.

I didn't found any solution for this, so I've just created my own library for that: [react-native-xml](https://github.com/artemyarulin/react-native-xml) which allows you to parse xml and make XPath queries for it:

```
let xml = require('NativeModules').RNMXml
xml.find('<doc a="V1">V2</doc>', 
         ['/doc/@a', '/doc'], 
          results => results.map(nodes => console.log(nodes[0]))) 
// Output: 
//  V1 
//  V2
```

Comment: Very pretty solution but it does not seem to support Android. So you would still have the same problem there.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you cannot get XML back but you can get the raw text; use `response.text()` instead of `response.json()`. you will still need to process the text into xml

Comment: Yes, response.text() works fine, but there is a problem with text to xml process. For example all solutions from [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript) answers return null or error :(

Comment: Also i've got "Can't find variable: DOMParser()" when using new DOMParser();

Answer (score 1):

I am using react-native, and I didn't really like xmldom.
I wrote my own react-native XML parser.
You can check it on
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xml-parser

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of 2 packages. In my use case I had to parse response of a SOAP request:

The first package is - [React Native XML2JS](https://github.com/connected-io/react-native-xml2js) The reason for using it and not [XML2JS](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) is I was getting an error of [React Native not supporting node standard library](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo). (I am using expo as well.)

The second package which I actually used for parsing is - [XML-JS](https://github.com/nashwaan/xml-js). I had to use the first package as I was getting the same error of React Native not supporting node standard library. I used this because it gave a more structured result in case of a large XML response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with xml2js :

• responseText is is the .XML data fetched from example.xml

• within the curly braces of .then((responseText) = {}) the xml2json script is added to parse the .xml data to Json format
console.log(result) will render the json format in the terminal.

side note : if you remove the parse string and add console.log(responseText) instead the output will be XML format.

```html
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {View} from 'react-native';
    import {parseString} from 'xml2js'



    class App extends Component {


     componentDidMount(){
      this._isMounted = true;
      var url = "https://example.xml"
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {
       parseString(responseText, function (err, result) {
         console.log(result);
         return result;
        });
      this.setState({
        datasource : result
        })
       })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error fetching the feed: ', error);
    });
  }



      componentWillUnMount() {
         this._isMounted = false;
      }




      render(){
        return(
          <View>

          </View>

        )
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;

fetch('link')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then((response) => {
        parseString(response, function (err, result) {
            console.log(response)
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('fetch', err)
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem spend a few hours before I found out that I could do it like this:

```
const GOOGLE_FEED_API_URL = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=-1&q="
let url = GOOGLE_FEED_API_URL + encodeURIComponent(<yoururl>);

fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How come this is upvoted? It answers a totally different question; how to send an URL as a get parameter.

Comment: I think it's using a Google service to convert an XML file into JSON…