# parsing directory listing of a webpage in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I need to parse the directory listing of an external webpage in AngularJS. I found a few solutions to this problem, but those are in PHP. Is there anyway I can do it in angularjs?

I am making a $http.get call to get the html. I want to parse the html and convert into a json or xml. The structure of the html is as shown below

```
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <th> <img src = "abc.jpg"></th>
               ....
           </tr>
        </tbody>
    <table> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http.get` will give you the HTML content of the remote page. Parsing it has nothing to do with Angular. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17604312/183386) for solutions, as HTML is a form of XML.

Once you have built your JSON structure, Angular can nicely display it.

Comment: thanks :) ... i just wanted to know if there was any inbuilt function in angularjs to parse html data.