# How to convert xml data into var list JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, asp.net-web-api

I am working with .NET Web API which returns data/xml (list)...

I want to consume this API into JavaScript function and convert response into var list like

```
var statusList = [{
                   "text": "Completed"
               },{
                   "text": "Not-Completed"
               },{
                   "text": "Started"
               },{
                   "text": "Not-Started"
               }];
```

XML response
[image]
How can i do that, or any kind of reference will be appreciated.

Comment: @dandavis thanks for reply, i don't understand, what do you mean sir???

Comment: Please look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript