# importing xml in htm with jquery and sorting data with tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, tablesorter

I am using jquery to get xml data into html (table). ( classical Javascript coding only work if you are doint it through a webserver but I am currently not interested in to work on a webserver.

The call function to read my xml data works fine(in Firefox only ) I would like alos to make use of the **tablesorter** jquery plugin. Unfortunatly, when I use it it doesn't work...Any clue on what could be wrong with code ? Is it perhaps I am using tablesorter in the wrong place..? Any alternative of proceeding is welcome (bear in mind that I am not working on a webserver).

here is the link of tablesorter plugin:
[home page tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

the data called sites:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
   <root>
    <snapshot>
     <order>1</order> 
     <screen>1</screen> 
     <randomised>0</randomised> 
    </snapshot>
    <snapshot>
     <order>2</order> 
     <screen>2</screen> 
     <randomised>1</randomised> 
    </snapshot>
  </root>
```

the code  has two calls one for calling tablesorter plugin and one to read xml data using jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    }
   th, td {
    padding: 5px;
   }
</style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"type="tex/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script> 


<script>
 //initialise my html table below for get ready to do sorting by calling tablesorter plugin
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#metrics").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
//import xml data into html
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "sites.xml", 
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {  


   $(xml).find('snapshot').each(function(){ 
    var Cl0 = $(this).find("order").text();
    var Cl1 = $(this).find("screen").text();
    var Cl2 = $(this).find("randomised").text();
    $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+Cl0+'</td><td>'+Cl1+'</td><td>'+Cl2+'</td>').appendTo('#metrics');
   });
  }
 });
 });

</script>
</head>

<body>
      <p>This is my table.</p>
 <table id="metrics" class="tablesorter" >
  <tr><th>Order</th><th>screen</th><th>randomised</th></tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers

saskap

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, mate: 
[Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: Also, make sure to use `$("#metrics").trigger('update');` *after* the new content is added to the table (after the `.each()` function).