# Cannot make a simple http GET call in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to make a simple http `GET` request from my Angular2 app:

```
    this.http.get("https://mybaseurl.com/hello")
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
    function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
    function() { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
  );
```

The `Node.js` server is configured this way:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
  res.send("hellow world");
});
```

When I make the call I keep getting this error:

```
    caused by: unable to parse url 'https://mybaseurl.com/hello'; original error: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
   at InMemoryBackendService.parseUrl (in-memory-backend.service.ts:518)
    at InMemoryBackendService.handleRequest (in-memory-backend.service.ts:279)
    at InMemoryBackendService.createConnection (in-memory-backend.service.ts:240)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

edit: pasting the entire class code:

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Auth} from './auth.service';
import {AuthHttp} from 'angular2-jwt';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'ping',
  templateUrl: 'app/ping.template.html'
})
export class ApiService {

  API_URL: string = 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com';
  message: string;

  constructor(private auth: Auth, private http: Http, private authHttp: AuthHttp) {}

  public ping() {

    this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/hello`)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe((response) => { 
        console.log("Success Response" + response)
        },
        (error) => { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
        () => { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
    ); 
  }    
}
```

=====>
This looks like a HUGE bug in Angular2 - all `http requests` return null, or an error message describing it is not in the required pattern. 
I someone has a working demo of `HTTP GET` I would love to see

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an issue with the code above. A suggestion - use `() =>` instead of `function()` because `function()` will cause `this.` not pointing to the current class instance anymore. Perhaps you have this already outside the code you posted which causes errors here.

Comment: I am calling from localhost to heroku app (https://myherokuapp.com). Is this related?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this didn't help. The very weird thing is what I try to call a working service that returns a JSON, I get: `Error with status: 404 Not Found for URL: null`

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more code. I wouldn't expect to help in above code because there you don't use `this` (except with `this.http(...)`.

Comment: Do you have ```<base href="/">``` in your index.html? Does it work if you use ```"mybaseurl.com/hello"``` without the ```https://```?

Comment: Yes. Server and client have different url

Comment: i think here you find your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628496/anglarjs2-http-get-request-error-unable-to-parse-url-original-error-cann

Comment: This is not the case - I am not using `InMemoryBackendService`..

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have tried everything. Event the simplest http call is not working. regardless of what is the service. Is this related to the fact that I am calling from `localhost` to a remote server ?

Comment: Have you tried using a literal string of the URL instead of `${this.API_URL}/hello`?

Comment: Yes. of course.. does not work. This is driving me crazy :(

Comment: @Silvermind, how do I set `RequestOptions`?

Comment: It's the second argument to the get call. Right after the url.

Comment: @Silvermind This is done. But at this point I keep getting error `404 Not Found for URL: null`

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in a Plunker? Plunker provides a ready to use Angular2 TS template under the `[ New | V ]` button

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer while working on the reproduction I found the issue - caused by using `InMemoryWebApiModule` (which has a very poor documentation in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like using `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)` in `@NgModule` simultaneously with `Http.get` causes uncovered urls to return null and error.

Setting it this way worked for me:
`InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {passThruUnknownUrl: true})`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is beacause of your answer from server - you send string to client, but in map function you try to call res.json(). Can you comment map function call?

Answer (score 0):

Check by using arrow function for success and error as below :

```
this.http.get("https://mybaseurl.com/hello")
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe((response) => { console.log("Success Response" + response)},
    (error) => { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
    () => { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
);
```