# Angular2: Convert XML to JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services, angular2-nativescript

I wanted to convert the XML I received from Web API response to JSON in Angular 2. The application is developed in Nativescript. Not able to find a solution for this.

Comment: Did you tried this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-xml2js

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368405/how-to-parse-xml-in-angular-2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse xml in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368405/how-to-parse-xml-in-angular-2)

Comment: As informed by Nativescript team and as experimented, none of the above said modules seems to be working with nativescript angular 2. So is there any other alternatives which can be used with nativescript angular 2.

Comment: Weird, so you looked up support for the nativescript-xml2js and it said it it does not work for nativescript?

Comment: nativescript-xml2js wont work with nativescript. They said like the author of the plugin is not an active member and this is not something which is supported in nativescript. Just the name is confusing. Nativescript has not yet provided a proper solution for this.

Answer (score 7):

I found an amazing package to make this very simple.

[xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)

For me on I am doing it in an angular 2 application but on the node side.

```
npm install xml2js --save
```

It is literally as simple as passing the xml like this,

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

In my app I had an xml file and used it like this,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

function requestCreditReport(callback) {
    fs.readFile('./credit-api/response.xml', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        parseString(data, callback);
    });
}
```

[See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdmob/gkxucxrj/1/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Somehow i am not able see the log inside the parseAtring function. Soap envelop is my response from web api.

Comment: So you are saying that you are trying to console result and it is not working?   would you please console.log outside of the function a test. To make sure we are running the file.

Comment: The console.dir is not working and i am not sure how to get the result out of it.                 var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});

Comment: try this, var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString; var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"; var jString = parseString(xml); console.log(jString);

Comment: I am getting the below error when i try to use the xml2js module.                 03-17 02:37:48.190: V/JS(7130): error ::: Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "events", relative to: app/tns_modules/
03-17 02:37:48.190: V/JS(7130):     com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:159)
03-17 02:37:48.190: V/JS(7130):     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:60)
03-17 02:37:48.190: V/JS(7130):     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)

Comment: I do not know for sure if that will work for nativescript. But here is an event module. This could have something else to do with your app https://www.npmjs.com/package/events

Comment: Wait see if this makes a difference https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-xml2js

Comment: Also this might help you too https://runkit.com/npm/nativescript-xml2js

Comment: using nativescript-xml2js.I am getting the below exception.'Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException:Failed to find module: "xml2js", relative to: app/tns_modules/'                       the i am using is below,                                                                                       getJsonfromXml() {
 
        try{
            let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
   let xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>";
   parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.dir(result);
   });
  } catch (e){
   console.log("error :: "+e);
  }
    }

Comment: As informed by Nativescript team and as experimented, none of the above said modules seems to be working with nativescript angular 2. So is there any other alternatives which can be used with nativescript angular 2.

Answer (score 6):

This is if you are doing a POST and getting back XML response using Angular 2: Use xml2js - https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js

1. npm install xml2js --save
2. import in service file as:

   ```
   import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';
   ```
3. Code:

   ```
   let formdata = new URLSearchParams();
   formdata.set('username','username');
   formdata.set('pw','pw'); 
   let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, method: RequestMethod.Post});

   postData () {

        this.http.post(this._yourUrl, formdata.toString(), options)
        //convert to JSON here
        .map(res => {
               xml2js.parseString( res.text(), function (err, result) {
               console.dir(result); // Prints JSON object!
            });
        })
        .subscribe(data => { 
             console.log(data);              
        });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseXml(xmlStr) {
    var result;
    var parser = require('xml2js');
    parser.Parser().parseString(xmlStr, (e, r) => {result = r});
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Add some more context to your code to help future readers better understand its purpose.