# Converting XML API response to JSON in Angular

Tags: json, xml, angular

I am receiving data from an API that uses XML instead of JSON. So far I have the following service for connecting to the API:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private searchURL: string = "http://api.testsite.xml";
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getData(){
    return this._http.get(this.searchURL).map(res => res)
  }
}
```

I subscribe to it in my component like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._service.getData().subscribe(item=> console.log((<any>item)._body));
  }
```

This returns a Response object inside which there's a `_body` property where the whole XML is stored as a string. How do I go about extracting this XML and convert it to JSON? Thanks.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838285/angular2-convert-xml-to-json

Comment: I agree with @Ali, you'll need a 3rd party tool to parse that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -
**xml2json.js** library. Found this at - [Here](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/)

```
var x2js = new X2JS();
var jsonString = x2js.xml_str2json(yourXml);
```