# How to parse XML data to an angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, dom

Fox example I have the following XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
       <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="web">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
    <book category="web" cover="paperback">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

How could I parse this data and render it using angular component and display. How to access the data and fetch the result using angular

Comment: Please refer to the numerous questions already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368405/how-to-parse-xml-in-angular-2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse xml in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368405/how-to-parse-xml-in-angular-2)