# Angular 5 httpClient version of code

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some code which works for me in it's current format but I would like to change it so it uses angular httpClient instead.

Here is the current code:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
const xml = XMLData;
xhr.open('PUT', 'my url here', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/xml');
xhr.send(xml);
const response = xhr.responseText;
```

How can I do this with Angular 5's ***httpClient*** PUT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse xml in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368405/how-to-parse-xml-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what an PUT request with [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-put-request) and options could look like. You will need to transform your `XMLData`, whatever that may be, to a string. The SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368405/how-to-parse-xml-in-angular-2) provided by @Vikas in his comment mentions a few libraries that are effective at parsing XML.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  doPut() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
      })
    };

    const xml: string = '<foo>1</foo>';

    return this.http.put("/some/url", xml, httpOptions)
      .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
  }
}
```

Consolidated version if you prefer:

```
doPut(xml: string) {    
  return this.http.put("/some/url", xml, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' }) })
    .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
}
```

The HTTP request will NOT execute unless you `subscribe()` to the returned `Observable` produced by `put()` somewhere. I'd additionally review the documentation for error handling and additional options/functionality.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Can't I put the const and subscribe bit inside the doPut() function?

Comment: This is a simplified example. Usually you'd simply `return this.http.put("/some/url", xml, httpOptions)` which returns an `Observable` and subscribe in something like `@Component` that injects this service and calls the `doPut()` method of the service. You can arrange this any way you'd need. This was more to show the PUT using HttpClient at the most basic level.

Comment: I should clarify that this does NOT need to be called in an `@Injectable`. `HttpClient` can be injected into effectively any `@Injectable` or `@Component`. You could execute the `put()` of an `HttpClient` instance anywhere you need, it does not need to be in a method called `doPut()`. This is showing how to create/add headers such as `Content-Type`, executing the request, and reading the results. Does that help clarify?