# Fetch some data from xml response comes from ajax jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have ajax call with type post and in success I get xml response as per below .And I want to fetch "This is Response" from the response displayed below.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "xml",
                url: serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web",
                data: requestXML,
                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
                    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                    debugger;
                    if (XmlHttpRequest.status === 200) {
                        var response = XmlHttpRequest.responseXML;
                        alert(XmlHttpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

Response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><ExecuteResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services"><ExecuteResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><a:ResponseName>new_PASMcreateProject</a:ResponseName><a:Results xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"><a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType><b:key>Response</b:key><b:value i:type="c:string" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">This is response</b:value></a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType></a:Results></ExecuteResult></ExecuteResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Please suggest me the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked with data in success method?

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "xml",
                url: serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web",
                data: requestXML,
                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
                    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                   alert($(XmlHttpRequest.responseText).find('b\\:value').text()); // check this in console.log
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

You can see in console with object.. you can retrieve data from object easily...
something like

```
$(data).find('b\\:value').text();
```

Comment: Hi Haresh,I checked in console but it displayed same response as I got.

Comment: @chhaya_patel, I got soluion, check with `$(data).find('b\\:value').text();`

Comment: if you like and correct please mark as right and upvote also ;)

Comment: Hi I am getting no value with use of $(data).find('b\\:value').text();.it gives me " ".

Comment: try with `$(XmlHttpRequest.responseText).find('b\\:value').text()`

Comment: Yes I finally got the answer with $(XmlHttpRequest.responseText).find('b\\:value').text().Thanx a lot.

Comment: Its glad to hear from you and help to you... thanks very much.. basically from where are you?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). If you want to use raw text, you can use `XmlHttpRequest.responseText`

If you want to use XML format, use [jQuery parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse the returned XML. For example:

```
...
success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
  if (XmlHttpRequest.status === 200) {
    var responseXML = $.parseXML(XmlHttpRequest.responseXML),
      $responseXML = $(responseXML),
      $responseValue = $responseXML.find('b\\:value');
    console.log(responseXML);
  }
},
...
```

Or using plain Javascript (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript))

```
...
success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
  if (XmlHttpRequest.status === 200) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    responseXML = parser.parseFromString(XmlHttpRequest.responseXML, "text/xml");
    var response = responseXML.getElementsByTagName('b\\:value')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;              
    console.log(response);
  }
},
...
```

Comment: Hi Firice Nguyen , I get null value in responsexml  with the use of $.parseXML

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` ? And which version of `jQuery` are you using?

Comment: Yes . I am using <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>

Comment: Or you can use plain Javascript, see my updated answer

Comment: Hi with your old answer now I can get value in var responsexml with change of XmlHttpRequest.responseText instead XmlHttpRequest.responseXML.but I am not getting exact b:value in console it gives object

Comment: And in your 2nd solution I get error in var response = responseXML.getElementsByTagName('b:value')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; because it gives null value for responseXML.getElementsByTagName('b:value')

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked the code. Seems it should change to `b\\:value`, updated