# Javascript iteration through XML tags

Tags: javascript, xml, xml2js

I have the following output from `GET` request:

```
<VALUE1>value1</VALUE1>
<VALUE2>value2</VALUE2>
...
<VALUEn>valuen</VALUEn>
```

I need to get all these values in an array like:

```
[
    value1,
    value2
    ....
    value
]
```

I tried to iterate increment a value for example `val` and then put it on `VALUE` tag like so - `VALUE[val]` but no luck.
I use `xml2js` library and the output I have is `value.VALUE`. I can accsess very first value by `value.VALUE1` but how should I iterate to reach all the values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)

Comment: Or [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript) or about 100 other questions/answers

Comment: If I ask a question it means I already spent some time while googling it.

Comment: So why does neither of those question answer your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath is another alternate to get it fairly easily

```
var outputArray = [];
var xml = http.responseXML;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var tagValue = xml.evaluate('string(/ex:value'+ i +')',
                              xml,
                              nsResolver,
                              XPathResult.STRING_TYPE,
                              null);
    outputArray.push(tagValue.stringValue);
 }
```

You can read about XPath Evaluate [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate)