# Check if 2 XML documents are identical with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have 2 xml documents stored which I get from an AJAX post request and I would like to check if they are the same. Obviously `xml1 == xml2` is not working. Is there another way that I could make this work?

Comment: There's no built-in way to do that in JavaScript. You'll have to come up with code that performs a comparison between the DOM trees using whatever criteria suit your application.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you. That's what I thought but I wanted to make sure that there is not a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It parses the XML document using the method in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript) and compares the two using [isEqualNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isEqualNode).

```js
function parseXMLString(xmlString) {
  var xmlDoc;

  if (window.DOMParser) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
  } else // Internet Explorer
  {
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString);
  }

  return xmlDoc;
}

var xmlObj1 = parseXMLString('<hello>world</hello>');

var xmlObj2 = parseXMLString('<hello>world</hello>');

var xmlObj3 = parseXMLString('<hello>world2</hello>');

var xmlObj4 = parseXMLString('<hello2>world</hello2>');

console.log(xmlObj1.isEqualNode(xmlObj2));
console.log(xmlObj1.isEqualNode(xmlObj3));
console.log(xmlObj1.isEqualNode(xmlObj4));
```

If you're using jQuery, you can parse the XML document using [parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).