# Putting XML data in <li> tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, html-lists

I'm making a list with items from a Sharepoint site. I'm requesting this data with xmlhttprequest. I can request the data but I also want to put it in a unordered list automatically. I'm stuck where I need to put the XML data in the li tag.

JavaScript code:

```
function loadUsers(){

    //vraag request aan server
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // server link en geeft aan of sync of Async is
  xhr.open('GET', 'Website-URL', true);

    // maak nieuwe function voor het laden
  xhr.onload = function(){

      // als de status van de server gelijk is aan 200 doe dan de data uit de site in een lijst zetten.
    if(this.status == 200){
      var users = JSON.parse(this.responseText);


      var output = '';
      for(var i in users){
        output +=
          '<div class="user">' +
          '<ul>' +
          '<li id="ID">ID: '+properties[0].d:Title+'</li>' +
          '<li id="Login">Login: '+properties[0].d:Created+'</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
          '</div>';
      }

      document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = output;
    }
  }

  xhr.send();
}
```

this is a part of the xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:cf="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/rss/core/2005"><channel base="https://asml.sharepoint.com/teams/edev-sharepoint-training/Stefan/Subsite_Stefan/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/" xmlns:cfi="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/rss/core/2005/internal" cfi:lastdownloaderror="None"><title cf:type="text">SubsiteList</title><cf:guid isPermaLink="false">https://asml.sharepoint.com/teams/edev-sharepoint-training/Stefan/Subsite_Stefan/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/SubsiteList/</cf:guid><atom:updated>2017-11-13T08:36:45Z</atom:updated><lastBuildDate>Mon, 13 Nov 2017 08:36:45 GMT</lastBuildDate><atom:link href="SubsiteList" rel="self" title="SubsiteList"/><item><guid isPermaLink="false">https://asml.sharepoint.com/teams/edev-sharepoint-training/Stefan/Subsite_Stefan/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/SubsiteList(2)</guid><title xmlns:cf="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/rss/core/2005" cf:type="text">Test</title><atom:updated xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">2017-10-25T08:43:22Z</atom:updated><atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="SubsiteList(2)" rel="edit" title="SubsiteListItem"/><atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="SubsiteList(2)/Gender" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Gender" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Gender"/><atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="SubsiteList(2)/Language" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Language" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Language"/><atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="SubsiteList(2)/Status" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Status" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Status"/><atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="SubsiteList(2)/CreatedBy" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CreatedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="CreatedBy"/><atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="SubsiteList(2)/ModifiedBy" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ModifiedBy" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ModifiedBy"/><atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" href="SubsiteList(2)/Attachments" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Attachments" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Attachments"/><category domain="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme">Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.SubsiteListItem</category><content type="application/xml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <m:properties>
    <d:ContentTypeID>0x01002301B0B520E8D14CA4D7938BD72EBA26</d:ContentTypeID>
    <d:Title>Test</d:Title>
    <d:ComplianceAssetId m:null="true"/>
    <d:Description m:null="true"/>
    <d:Description0 m:null="true"/>
    <d:GenderValue m:null="true"/
    <d:CountryRegion m:null="true"/>
    <d:LanguageValue m:null="true"/>
    <d:ZIPPostalCode m:null="true"/>
    <d:StatusValue m:null="true"/>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:Id>
    <d:ContentType>Item</d:ContentType>
    <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-10-25T01:43:22</d:Modified>
    <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-10-25T01:43:22</d:Created>
    <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">23</d:CreatedById>
    <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">23</d:ModifiedById>
    <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Owshiddenversion>
    <d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
    <d:Path>/teams/edev-sharepoint-training/Stefan/Subsite_Stefan/Lists/Subsite list</d:Path>
  </m:properties>
```

The added code.

```
function loadUsers(){

    //vraag request aan server
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // server link en geeft aan of sync of Async is
  xhr.open('GET', 'Website-URL', true);

    // maak nieuwe function voor het laden
  xhr.onload = function(){



   // als de status van de server gelijk is aan 200 doe dan de data uit 
   de site in een lijst zetten.

    if(this.status == 200){
      var users = JSON.parse(this.responseText);


    if(window.DOMParser){

    parser = new DOMParser();

    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");

    }

    else{

    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

    xmlDoc.async = false;

    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
                                                                                            }



      var output = '';
      for(var i in users){
        output +=
          '<div class="user">' +
          '<ul>' +
          '<li id="ID">ID: '+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue+'</li>' +
          '<li id="Login">Login: '+properties[0].d:Created+'</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
          '</div>';
      }

      document.getElementById('properties').innerHTML = output;
    }
  }

  xhr.send();
}





        </script>
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDCwY.png)

Comment: Here is the link which shows how to parse xml data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript#17604312

Comment: i added the code above and its still not working. Can you please explain me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Is it throwing any error?

Comment: Yes its throwing these errors. (see screenshot above)

Comment: On first error, I think you are missing;  " " (quotation marks), on line 87.