# Updating Table or div Data using Ajax Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I am trying to create a page where it shows the current chats done by clients.
Now I am using Openfire as Server, and PHP Ajax for scripting.

Openfire dumps data into MySQL Table.
I retrive all the records using Codeigniter-PHP:

```
 public function get_chats()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('ofMessageArchive');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();


        $this->data['messages'] = $result;


        $this->data['subview'] = 'dashboard/test';
        $this->load->view('_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
```

Now on my view I have table :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
         <thead>
             <th>From</th>
             <th>To</th>
             <th>Message</th>
             <th>Time</th>
         </thead>

         <tbody>
            <?php if(count($messages)): foreach($messages as $key => $message): ?> 
            <tr> 
                <td><?php  $users =  explode("__", $message->fromJID); echo $users[0];?></td>
                <td><?php $tousers =  explode("__", $message->toJID); echo $tousers[0];  ?></td>
                <td><i class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i>Message</td>
                <td><?php echo $date->format('d-m-y H:i:s'); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now I don't want to reload the whole page instead just refresh the table contents every 5 seconds.

I am using **DataTables**.

I also thought I could pass json to my view, but I don't know how to update it every 5 seconds.

```
public function get_chats()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('ofMessageArchive');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();


        if (count($result)) {
            $response =  json_encode($result);
        }
        else
        {
            $response = false;
        }

        echo $response;
    }
```

Also this is going to send new and older messages.
So I only want to append news messages to table old message should be not repeated

Comment: its called long pooling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backend function :

```
 public function get_chats()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('ofMessageArchive');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();


        if (count($result)>0) {
            $response['status']= true;
            $response['messages']= $result;
            $response['date']= date("d-m-y H:i:s", strtotime($your-date-here));
        }
        else
        {
            $response['status']=false;
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

You have to make javascript function like this :

```
<script>

function myAJAXfunction(){
 $.ajax({
     url:'your url here',
     type:'GET',
     dataType:'json',
     success:function(response){
         console.log(response);

         var trHTML='';
         if(response.status){
           for(var i=0;i<response.messages.length;i++){

              users =response.messages[i]fromJID.slice('--');
              touser=response.messages[i]toJID.slice('--');

              trHTML=trHTML+
              '<tr>'+
               '<td>'+users[0]+'</td>'+
               '<td>'+touser[0]+'</td>'+
               '<td><i class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i>Message</td>'+
               '<td>'+response.date+'</td>'+
               </tr>';
         }

           $('tbody').empty();
           $('tbody').append(trHTML);

         }else{
           trHTML='<tr><td colspan="4">NO DATA AVAILABLE</td></tr>';
           $('tbody').empty();
           $('tbody').append(trHTML);
         }

     },
     error:function(err){
        alert("ERROR LOADING DATA");
     }
 });
}


// calling above ajax function  at every 5 seconds

setInterval(myAJAXfunction,5000);

</script>
```

Comment: hey Saurabh thanks! I am getting this error  ::  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on this line :::  `users =response.messages[i]fromJID.slice('__');`

Comment: aslo should i make any changes in my html ??

Comment: try to print this first : `console.log(response.messages[i]fromJID)`

Comment: I solved that, but last question :) I get this is message : `<message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="" from="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC"><body>OFFLINE_READ_RECEIPT</body><cha:active xmlns:cha="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"></cha:active></message>`

Comment: i want to check/get if the message contains:: OFFLINE_READ_RECEIPT in body

Comment: How do i acess the body part of the message?? as its XML

Comment: when you will getting this XML message ?

Comment: Everytime this jquery function is called i have defined a variable like message =  response[i].stanza; now in this variable message actually contains XML data so i want to check the body field of this XML data

Comment: You need to do XML parsing using Javascript in your response : hope this link will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript

Comment: Works Now As Required !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168916/discussion-between-rajan-and-saurabh-mistry).