# how to parse xml files field tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, solr, nutch

i have a xml file which has field tags like

```
    <!-- fields for index-anchor plugin -->
    <field name="anchor" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- fields for index-more plugin -->
    <field name="type" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="contentLength" type="long" stored="true"
        indexed="false"/>
```

how to parse the xml field tags using javascript
I have tried the following code but of no use

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "schema.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
  var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  txt = "";
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("field");
    for (i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
    txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue +"<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript

Comment: but the answer does not tell about field tags parsing of xml

Comment: Please see the answer for reference for sample field tags

Comment: The name of the XML element shouldn't matter - how use parse XML is the same in both cases. You parse the XML, then use `getElementsByTagName` and friends to retrieve the nodes you're interested in. What doesn't work in your example? What are you trying to extract? What do you want the result to be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess thid would work :

```js
var text = `
    <!-- fields for index-anchor plugin -->
    <field name="anchor" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- fields for index-more plugin -->
    <field name="type" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="contentLength" type="long" stored="true"
        indexed="false"/>
`;

if (window.DOMParser)
{
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer 
{
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
}


console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("field")[0].getAttribute("name"));
```

Comment: this does not give any output (blank)

Comment: It is giving the result "anchor" for attribute "name". See the output when clicking on "Run Code Snippet "