# convert simple description data which contains tags into array

Tags: arrays, string, reactjs, react-native

I have description data like :

```
"<question> This is question 1? </question> 
<answer> This is answer 1 </answer>
<question> this is question 2? </question>
<answer> This is answer </answer>"
```

---

Desired Output is :

```
 desc= {
   [question: "This is question 1?", answer: "This is answer 1"], 
   [question: "this is question 2?", answer: "This is answer 2] 
 }
```

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: This will give you a start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
const desc = "<question> This is question 1? </question><answer> This is answer 1 
</answer><question> this is question 2? </question><answer> This is answer </answer>";

var questions = desc.match(/<question>(.*?)<\/question>/g).map(function(val){
return val.replace(/<\/?question>/g,'');
});

var answers = desc.match(/<answer>(.*?)<\/answer>/g).map(function(val){
return val.replace(/<\/?answer>/g,'');
});

var arrayList = questions.map((item,index) => {
return {question:item, answer: answers[index]}
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayList));
```

Working solution:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NeWEdz