# Extract a value from an XML string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am facing the following problem:

I am given a XML string and a message (string) I need a function that can parse the XML string and return an array of ids for the XML tags (id="x") in which the message is present.

I can only use JavaScript for this.

```js
function getIdByMessage(xml, message) {
// problem to solve
}

var xml = `
<test>blabla</test>
<otherstuff>MoreStuff</otherstuff>
<message-not-relevant>Not relevant</message-not-relevant>
<entry id="4">Function Message<entry>
<otherstuff>MoreStuff</otherstuff>
<message-not-relevant>Not relevant</message-not-relevant>
<entry id="3">Function Message<entry>
<otherstuff>MoreStuff</otherstuff>
<message-not-relevant>Not relevant</message-not-relevant>
`

getIdByMessage(xml, 'Function Message'); // should return [4, 3];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parse the XML into a DOM: see for example [Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)

Then, on the resulting DOM Document object, execute the XPath expression

```
//entry[. = 'Function Message']/@id
```

This will return a set of attribute nodes.

Comment: thank you so much, I was not aware of the DOMParser. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what might be in the xml you don't necessarily have to parse it. You might get away with just searching it for id="number"

For example:

```
let matches = xml.match(/id="[\d]+"/gm);
let entryIds = matches.map(m => m.match(/\d+/)[0]));
```

Or match the whole tag on the first line.

Comment: That's generally bad advice. We get an awful lot of questions on StackOverflow saying, in effect, "I need to generate my XML in a very specific format because the recipient isn't using a proper XML parser to process it".

Comment: If you have a schema, and you know that, say, only one tag comes with an id, or that the entry tag has only the id attribute, then you can formulate a regular expression that will match any XML file that matches the schema. So, if the entry tag is only present at one place in the schema, and can only have an id attribute then /<entry\s+id\s*=\s"\d+"\s*>/ isn't likely to fail.

Comment: You consider being "unlikely to fail" as good enough? How unlikely does it have to be? Your regex doesn't even allow the attribute to be in single quotes rather than double quotes. Regex solutions ALWAYS have that kind of bug; in fact computer science theory tells you that a regular expression CANNOT be written that always works, because XML is not a regular language.

Comment: And if you don't believe that, here's an exercise: write a regex that will match `<entry id="xxxx">` *provided it hasn't been commented out*.

Comment: Fair point. I've seen so many cases though where people have used a heavyweight tool where I lightweight one will do what is required, with far less effort.