# How to create an HTML page with a given XML file?

Tags: html, xml

I've read and converted a file into a XML file. The file format will always be as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<family>
    <person>
        <id>I1@</id>
        <name>Joao</name>
        <father>I2@</father>
        <mother>I3@</mother>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>I5@</id>
        <name>Joao</name>
        <father>I2@</father>
        <mother>I3@</mother>
    </person>
</family>
```

With this i need to create a simple HTML page, that would still keep the XML format and maybe even allow me to style, for example, the tags colors, so they would still be showing in a different color like on the XML. I've tried putting everything inside a  but it just shows everything in black.

Comment: Please check if this helps [Using browsers DOMParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)

Comment: What do you use for creating HTML? What language or technology? E.g. python, java, c#, xslt...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using **xslt** where you can define how you want to transform each XML tag to HTML.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor/Basic_Example