# How to split XML path into an array in GAS

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

Searching a good way to split an XML path into an array. I have the feeling my solution is not as reliable as i want.

What I have: `<product><containeditem><productidentifier>`

What I want to get is an array like: `[product, containeditem, productidentifier]`

My Code:

```
function GetPathArray(path) {
  if (path != null) {
    path = path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
    path = path.substring(1);

    var pathArray = [{}];

    pathArray = path.split("><");

    return pathArray;
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have full/valid XML? Or just a very simple structure such as the one in your question? If it's just a simple fragment (e.g. no closing tags, no content, no attributes - just opening tags), then your approach is probably fine. But as soon as you have anything even slightly more complex, I would recommend you use an XML parser. For example, see [Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript) and similar questions.

Comment: For a broader discussion, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure you return an array, not a string, you can use this for the simple case in your question:

```js
var path = '<product><containeditem><productidentifier>';

console.log( getPathArray(path) );

function getPathArray(path){
  return path.slice(1, -1).split('><');
}
```

The `slice` function discards the first and last characters (the opening and closing `<` and `>`).

Then the `split` is all you need - as that returns an array.

For more complex strings, this will almost certainly not be sufficient.

Comment: After testing a lot, i think my code was working fine but, your way is just more clean and easier to read. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

As @andrewjames said, the solution depends on how the path looks like. If it is like your example, you can get the solution with basics string methods of JavaScript

### Code

```
function getPathArray(path){
  path = path.split('><').join(', ')
  path = path.replace('<','[')
  path = path.replace('>',']')
  return path
}
```

### References

- [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)