# Js Regex , how to get the closest tag?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below xml string. i want to use js Regex to query the closest '`<and>`' and replace it with something.

```html
<Query><Where><And><In><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>kk</Value></In><And><In><FieldRef Name='DocIcon' /><Value Type='Computed'>bb</Value></In><And><In><FieldRef Name='Continent' /><Value Type='Choice'>Europe</Value></In><Eq><FieldRef Name='Constituency' /><Value Type='Choice'>Jordan</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where></Query>
```

Formatted:

```html
<Query>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <In>
            <FieldRef Name='Title' />
            <Value Type='Text'>kk</Value>
         </In>
         <And>
            <In>
               <FieldRef Name='DocIcon' />
               <Value Type='Computed'>bb</Value>
            </In>
            <And>
               <In>
                  <FieldRef Name='Continent' />
                  <Value Type='Choice'>Europe</Value>
               </In>
               <Eq>
                  <FieldRef Name='Constituency' />
                  <Value Type='Choice'>Jordan</Value>
               </Eq>
            </And>
         </And>
      </And>
   </Where>
</Query>
```

[image]

`<Eq><FieldRef Name="Constituency" /><Value Type="Choice">Jordan</Value></Eq>` is a fixed string, other parts are not. which means there maybe many `<and> <In>`. How to get the closet `<and>`?

I tried below regex but fail:

```html
/(<And>)<In>.*<\/In>(<Eq><FieldRef Name="Constituency" \/><Value Type="Choice">Jordan<\/Value><\/Eq>)<\/And>/gi
```

[image]

Comment: And this is the time again to link to [this famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Don't use regex for this.

Comment: You need either XPath or settle for jQuery's [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method. There is practically zero reason to do this with regex unless you're not actually programming in JS and are hobbled by the UI of some system.

Answer (score 0):

This is better done by **parsing XML**.

See:

- [Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)
- https://javascript-html5-tutorial.com/xml-in-javascript.html
- https://www.educba.com/xml-parsing-in-javascript/

#### DOMParser and filter

For example to get all nodes inside your XML that have the tag-name `And` use the JavaScript `DOMParser`:

```js
xml = "<Query><Where><And><In><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>kk</Value></In><And><In><FieldRef Name='DocIcon' /><Value Type='Computed'>bb</Value></In><And><In><FieldRef Name='Continent' /><Value Type='Choice'>Europe</Value></In><Eq><FieldRef Name='Constituency' /><Value Type='Choice'>Jordan</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where></Query>"

const parser = new DOMParser();
let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

const andElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("And");
console.log("<And> elements found: ", andElements.length);

function containsEqFieldRef(e) {
     return e.childNodes[1].tagName == 'Eq' && e.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].tagName == 'FieldRef';
}
let found = Array.from(andElements).filter(containsEqFieldRef);
console.log("found <And> with ./Eq/FieldRef:", found);
```

Now you need to make the node-position for `Eq` variable.

For the JS DOM API related functions and classes:

- [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) class as returned from function `getElementsByTagName`
- [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) interface

#### XPath

as [suggested by MonkeyZeus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127007/js-regex-how-to-get-the-closest-tag/71127361?noredirect=1#comment125731578_71127007) XPath is the query-language for XML:

Read MDN: [Introduction to using XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) with examples:

```js
xml = "<Query><Where><And><In><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>kk</Value></In><And><In><FieldRef Name='DocIcon' /><Value Type='Computed'>bb</Value></In><And><In><FieldRef Name='Continent' /><Value Type='Choice'>Europe</Value></In><Eq><FieldRef Name='Constituency' /><Value Type='Choice'>Jordan</Value></Eq></And></And></And></Where></Query>"

const parser = new DOMParser();
let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

const xpathExpression = '//And[Eq/FieldRef]';
var xpathResult = xmlDoc.evaluate( xpathExpression, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
console.log(xpathResult.resultType);  // 4 for UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE 
console.log(xpathResult.iterateNext());
```

Try and test the XPath online: [xpather.com](http://xpather.com/4YO5mLmy). See also [XPath Cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)