# AngularJS as SOAP client

Tags: web-services, soap, angularjs

Is there a way to use angularJS as SOAP client or develop ng SOAP client service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. All what you need this is implement SOAP call on JavaScript. For example [Simplest SOAP example using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to that SO article from the main answer, you can probably use the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) instead of using the [XmlHttpRequest web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). The reason I would use $http instead is that it gives you promises and easier HTTP method handling out of the box.

Otherwise, this custom Angular $soap service [posted on this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490483/angularjs-soap-service-integration-with-angularjs-model), might give you what you want, which is also on [Github](https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap).