# Call a Control Method from ASP.NET MVC using JQuery / AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, wcf, soap

I have an application running in MS Silverlight(Client side) and Wcf SOAP service hosted in IIS (Business layer) and SQL (database). I'm asked to move the front end from silver light to ASP.NET or HTML 5. I'm thinking of couple of options and i need you guys input to finalize the solution.

1. Use ASP.NET MVC : ASPX -> View, Controler -> Calls SOAP service and fill the model. Works great.
2. Use ASP.NET MVC: ASPX -> View, Controler -> still calls the SOAP service, JQuery / AngularJS calls the contorler method to bind the data to view

I would like to know the PROS and CONS of # 2 option, even with the #1 option to. Please provide your valuable inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS + .net REST web services on the back-end, you don't really need server side MVC in this case. Just call the service, get json data and let angular take care about the presentation.

Comment: Thanks!. The issue is the service already out there which is a SOAP based service. I need to use that services only to build a the asp.net / angularjs. How do i communicate to soap service from angularjs? Is this required MVC to sit in client side to angularjs to communicate to soap service?

Comment: Ugh, SOAP is gonna be messy... But, here are some links that may help you to figure that out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490483/angularjs-soap-service-integration-with-angularjs-model
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124269/simplest-soap-example